# DJI Mavic 2 Pro send still images to a laptop in real-time

Tags: dji-mavic-2

Is it possible to send photos captured by a DJI Mavic 2 Pro to a laptop in real time?

Comment: Hello *just_learning* and welcome to Drones,SE! If you haven’t done so already, please read the [tour] and [ask]. Right now, your question is quite unclear/broad and risks being closed. Can I ask you to [edit] your question with more details like what you have tried so far? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to send still images in real-time to a laptop. For devices that take full size SD cards, you can get [WiFi enabled SD cards](https://www.google.com/search?q=WiFi+SD+cards) but I can't find a source for micro SD devices like the Mavic 2.

If you have a controller with HDMI-out, you could use an HDMI capture card on the laptop to receive live video from the drone and use an application on the laptop to capture stills from this. The quality would be lower (limited by video transmission settings) but you would get the instant images; if you also take a picture with the aircraft you could get the full resolution image once you landing.